# Encrypt Program error

Tags: python

I am writing an encrypt program in python in which I need to change the input string ex: HELLO and the output: LIPPS. I am having a problem when I type more one word.

```
def encr_ypt(s, n):
    word=ord(s)
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if word >= 90 and word <= 97:
            hsl = chr(63+n)
        if word >= 122:
            hsl = chr(95+n)
        else:
            hsl = chr(word+n)
    return hsl

st=raw_input('input string : ')
print encr_ypt(st, 4)
```

Here is the Error Message

```
input string : HELLO
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "encrypt.py", line 13, in <module>
    print encr_ypt(st, 4)
  File "encrypt.py", line 2, in encr_ypt
    word=ord(s)
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 5 found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ord(i)` fucntion takes a single character and then returns the ASCII value of resulting character. Your code is trying to get the ASCII value of a string , which returns an error.

Also since you are using `hsl` variable to store the encrypted string , be sure to use the `+=` operator which adds the resulting character to the string.

Here is the corrected Code

```
def encr_ypt(s, n):
    hsl = ''
    for word in s:
        word = ord(word)
        if word >= 90 and word <= 97:
            hsl += chr(63+n)
        if word >= 122:
            hsl += chr(95+n)
        else:
            hsl += chr(word+n)
    return hsl

st=raw_input('input string : ')
print encr_ypt(st, 4)
```

Comment: what best way i am writing 'U'V'W'Z' and the output is Character ? / ^ %, i want the output is back to 'A'